# AJAX Complete Response

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, fieldset

I have a password change function on my site and everything is done now, except I want to display a success or fail message. So here's my html:

```
<form id="change_Pass" action="" method="post">
    //stuff
</form>
<fieldset id="response_field_pass" style="display:none;"><p style="color:black;"></p></fieldset>
```

And my jquery:

```
$('#change_Pass').submit(function() {
    if(pass_val.form()) { 
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "script.php", 
            complete: function(data) {
                $('#response_field_pass').show();
                $('#response_field_pass >p').text(data);
                if(data) alert("success");
                else alert("fail");
            }
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```

The php scripts echos `true` or `false` so when successful i am getting an alert box that reads success. Which is great. But the fieldset is not showing and neither is the text that should be inside the `<p>`. It essentially just skips:

```
$('#response_field_pass').show();
$('#response_field_pass >p').text(data);
```

And moves on to the alerts. Any ideas why it isn't unhiding the fieldset?

Answer (score 1):

I doubt if it skips the lines you mentioned. Most probably the paragraph inside the fieldset has nothing to display, since first argument of `complete` handler is `jqXHR` object and not the data you receive from the server. In order to solve the problem I'd suggest you to use [`success`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) handler instead:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "script.php",
    success: function(data) {
        // ...
    }
});
```

The first argument of `success` function is `data` which is returned from the server.

To handle possible request errors, you can use `error` handler. It receives three arguments: The `jqXHR` object, a string describing the type of error that occurred and an optional exception object, if one occurred.

Comment: but is success okay? What if it fails? I just want it to display the response from the script after ajax completes.

Comment: @JohnBernal If the request fails you need to handle `error` callback. Otherwise, to get the data from the server you should use `success` handler, since the data get passed only in case of successful data transmission.

Comment: So I have [this](http://pastie.org/5095564) now, but the fieldset still won't show but the alert messages do. Any idea why the show is not firing off?

Comment: @JohnBernal Looks weird. It should work. Maybe you have problems in the markup or (stupid but may happen) the background of the fieldset is the same colour as the text?

Comment: the text color is black. No it's nothing like that, the fielset itself isn't even showing. At least I should be able to see the border but nothing. It's as if the fieldset is not there. Any ideas?